# Using sudoedit in a script (non-interactively)

Tags: bash, rhel, sudoedit

I'm looking to modify a file from a script. I can sudoedit the file as the `bob` user by doing

```
sudoedit -u bob /foo/bar.conf
```

but don't have rights to do anything else as bob.

I came across http://shadow-file.blogspot.com.au/2009/01/how-to-sudoedit-non-interactively.html which might work, but seems complicated.

Is there some trivial way to do this that I'm missing?

(In case you're wondering, I'm trying to edit the inputs.conf file for a Splunk Universal Forwarder install on a RHEL host with very restrictive permissions)

Comment: Check something like `sudo -u bob bash -c "echo 'spamegg' >> /foo/bar.conf"`

Comment: Thanks @heemayl, but I don't have rights to sudo anything as 'bob' - sudoedit for that particular file is literally all I can do.

Comment: You can't even specify the editor, that's configured. You'll have to talk to your administrator to get more privileges.

Comment: @glennjackman You can use whatever editor you like. The point of sudoedit is that the editor runs as you, but works on a temporary file, then sudoedit moves the content to the real file.

Comment: Oh, well, use `ed` which is easily scripted.

Comment: Thanks - will try out some combination of the method from the link above and using ed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the tips above about using `ed` (and [this example](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Ed_(text_editor)&oldid=658760649#Example)), I came up with the following

```
ED="/bin/ed"
CONTENT_TO_APPEND="Yay, config!"

##### Set editor #####
OLD_EDITOR=$EDITOR
export EDITOR=$ED;

##### Append using ed #####
echo "a
$CONTENT_TO_APPEND
.
w
q" | sudoedit -u bob /foo/bar.conf

##### Clean up #####
export EDITOR=$OLD_EDITOR
```

Comment: is it possible to do it with vi (or tee) instead of ed ?

Comment: Maybe using `ex` (`vi` is the visual mode for `ex`)? The important part is that the editor must support a non-interactive mode.

Comment: Finally i followed the link you give in your answer and got a solution :)